# Collection $\mathcal B=${$\bar A:A\in \mathcal A$} is locally finite,given that $\mathcal A$ is locally finite.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Let $\mathcal A$ be a locally finite collection of subsets of X.Then the collection $\mathcal B=${$\bar A:A\in \mathcal A$} of the closures of the element of $\mathcal A$ is locally finite.

### Proof:

Let $x\in X$ and $\mathcal A$ is locally finite,  so there exists a nbhd $U$ of $x$ that intersects only finitely many elements $A_1, A_2, A_3,..., A_n$ of $\mathcal A$.

More precisely,$A_i\cap U\neq \phi$,where $1\le i \le n $----------------$(1)$

Since,$A_i\subset \bar A_i$,so from $(1)$,we have $\bar A_i\cap U\neq \phi$,where $1\le i \le n $.

Hence,$U$ can intersect an atmost the same number of elements of $\mathcal B$ as that of $\mathcal A$.

**Is the proof correct?**

Comment: No, the proof is incorrect. There might be other elements of $\mathcal B$ intersecting $U$.

Comment: @Crostul:I also got some intuition that there might be some other elements that can intersect with $U,$ but  i was not able to recognize them.If I'm getting you correctly,you meant to say that there exists some $\bar A_j\in \mathcal B$ other than {$A_i:1\le i \le n$} such that $\bar A_j \cap U \neq \phi $?

Comment: @Crostul: then how we give the guarantee that there are only finitely many members of $\mathcal B$ that intersects with $U$ nontrivially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essential is here that for $U$ you can always choose an *open* neighborhood.

In that situation we have the implication:$$U\cap\overline A\neq\varnothing\implies U\cap A\neq\varnothing\tag1$$

Also the converse if this is true, but that is not relevant here.

$(1)$ assures us that the cardinality of the set $\{\overline A\mid A
\in\mathcal A\text{ and } U\cap \overline A\neq\varnothing\}$ will *not* exceed the set the cardinality of the set $\{A\in\mathcal A\mid U\cap A\neq\varnothing\}$.

So if $\{A\in\mathcal A\mid U\cap A\neq\varnothing\}$ is a finite set then so is $\{\overline A\mid A\in\mathcal A\text{ and } U\cap \overline A\neq\varnothing\}$ (QED).

Comment: In my post, I've proved the converse?

Comment: Yes. You proved the irrelevant side.

Comment: :Let $X=\mathbb R^2$ with product topology,choosing $U$={$(x,y):x>0,y>0$}=$(0,\infty)×(0,\infty)$ and fixing $A$={$(0,y):y∈\mathbb R$},then $U\cap \bar A\neq \phi$ but $U\cap A=\phi$..

Comment: :In the above argument (1) does not hold. What is the loophole in my example?

Comment: $A=\{(0,y)\mid y\in\mathbb R\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$ so that $A=\overline A$.

Comment: :oops...It did'nt clicked my mind...thanks a lot

Comment: Do you need a proof of $(1)$? I can add, if you like.

Comment: thank you,I got that....